# Keras Tuner Error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'function'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: keras, tensorflow, hyperparameter-tuning

I am working on a project where I have a dataset of emails with information such as subject, body, attachment names, etc. My goal is to classify/predict around ~5,000 different sites. I am using Keras Tuner to optimize my model, but I am encountering an error when running the tuner.search(train_evaluate_model) line.

**Here is the link to my Colab notebook:** [Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p0vcRAivheCmgsG8A__7utzd16KFCcmA)

**The error message I receive is as follows:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'function'>, <class 'NoneType'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RuntimeError: Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit of 3.

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'function'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix this error or any suggestions on additional information I should provide.